# Docker run with if statement within Docker Bamboo Task

Tags: bash, docker, bamboo

I would like to run a docker openjdk:8-jdk with the following command:

```
if [ "$GIT_BRANCH" = "master" ]; then ./gradlew publish; else echo Skipped because it is not master branch; fi
```

I tried to do the following:

```
docker run  --rm openjdk:8-jdk "if [ \"$GIT_BRANCH\" = \"master\" ]; then echo hi; else echo bla; fi"
```

But I get the following error: executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.

Furthermore it is not possible for me that I use the if statement like that:

```
if ...
  docker run ...
else
  echo Skipped
```

Because I have to run it as a bamboo docker task.

Answer (score 0):

Since the command above is not executed within bash, bash has to be started first like that:

```
docker run  --rm openjdk:8-jdk /bin/bash -c "if [ \"$GIT_BRANCH\" = \"master\" ]; then ./gradlew publish; else echo Skipped because it is not master branch; fi"
```